# Background Music Player While Switching Between Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I am making an music streaming application with music player in it. Now i want that users should be able to switch between activities while listening to music in the player. Also i would like to control and display info about the track being played in one activity.

I have tried implementing the MediaPlayer but is stops playing when i navigate to another activity. Any code example or pseudocode is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best option  for this is **Service**.., See this [Tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html).You can learn more [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) about services